# Connect Raspberry Pi to NRF24L01+

Tags: nrf24l01

I would like to connect the NRF24L01+ transceiver module to a `Raspberry Pi 2 Model B V1.1` and create a network connection between other `NRF24L01+` modules.

There are many how-to's on the internet explaining how to connect the `NRF24L01+` to an Arduino, but only a few of them explain connecting the `NRF24L01+` to a Raspberry Pi. Unfortunately, I could only find how-to's dedicated to older Raspberry Pi versions than the `Raspberry Pi 2 Model B V1.1`. Those lead to code compilation errors and problems with the different processors (ARMv6 and ARMv7).

Does anyone know a tutorial / how-to / step-by-step-instruction in how to connect a `NRF24L01+` to a `Raspberry Pi 2 Model B V1.1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://thedigitalryan.com/index.php/2015/05/24/raspberry-pi-2-and-arduino-with-nrf24l01-radios/

This one helped me. I had same problem, too.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use the SPI pins of your Raspberry Pi 2. You will find them here http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-73950/l/raspberry-pi-2-model-b-gpio-40-pin-block-pinout

RPi  --> nRF24L01+

17 --> Vcc

19 --> MOSI

21 --> MISO

23 --> SCK

25 --> GND

22 --> CE

24 or 26 --> CSN

Comment: Hi evgi9! Thank your for your help and the advice on the GPIO settings, but it still does not solve the `compilation errors` for using `Raspberry Pi 2 Model B V1.1`.

Comment: Your initial question was mainly about the hardware configuration. What kind of compilation errors do you have?

Comment: "Those lead to code compilation errors and problems with the different processors..."; usually the hardware 'connection' is not the issue.